# Github Actions automerge not working as expected

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a yml file with 5 jobs as below

1. build - working
2. unit tests - working
3. regression tests - working
4. create pull request - working
5. merge pull request - not working

The first 3 jobs work on my development branch so my file begins with

```
name: Spicethedeploy
on:
  push:
    branches: 
    - development
    
jobs:
```

Job 4 I specify this

```
source_branch: "development"                      
destination_branch: "master"
```

But when job 5 runs it looks for a pull request for development not master and does not complete. The code for this job is:

```
  automerge:
    needs: pull-request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: automerge
      uses: pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.13.1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}
```

Can someone tell me how to make this job look to the master branch?

I have created a second yml file called automerge.yml, contents below

```
name: automerge
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
    - master
    
jobs:
  automerge:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: automerge
      uses: pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.13.1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}        
        MERGE_LABELS: "automerge"
```

The pull request has also been removed from the first yml file which now stops after creating the pull request. The new yml file then kicks in and tries to merge but skips with this message

```
Run pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.13.1
2021-04-04T18:36:14.889Z INFO  Event name: pull_request
2021-04-04T18:36:15.102Z INFO  Skipping PR update, required label missing: automerge
2021-04-04T18:36:15.102Z INFO  Skipping PR merge, required label missing: automerge
```

Comment: Why not use GitHub's [own functionality](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/automatically-merging-a-pull-request) as suggested by that action's docs?

Comment: @Kev, could you share the whole workflow YAML file please? That way we can try to reproduce the error to find what is wrong.

Comment: Would it be an option to create another workflow specifically for `job 5`? This workflow would be triggered on PULL_REQUEST to the `master` branch and would be merged automatically if it comes from the `development` branch.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, looked into that, because I am on the free subscription that options is disabled.

Comment: @GuiFalourd, thanks for the response. You idea of creating a separate workflow is a potential, I will give that a go later and respond asap. Thanks

Comment: It's useful to include that research and context in the question.

Comment: @Kev: Looking at the automerge action documentation, it seems you have to add a `automerge` label to your PR to merge it automatically. Did you add it in your workflow?

Comment: @GuiFalourd, I have added to the original question. I am a step closer but just missing the last little piece I think.

Comment: I believe you just need to add the `automerge` label to your PR now. To do so you can use something like the add-label action (https://github.com/actions-ecosystem/action-add-labels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on **MERGE_LABELS:**    [here](https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action/#configuration) says -

> When an empty string ("") is given, all pull requests will be merged.

Following that, this worked for me

```
- id: automerge
    name: automerge
    uses: "pascalgn/automerge-action@v0.15.3"
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
      MERGE_LABELS: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GuiFalourd for the tips which pointed me in the right direction on this. Following his advice led me to this solution which works well

```
 merge:
    needs: pull-request
    name: merge
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: merge
      uses: mtanzi/action-automerge@v1
      id: merge
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}
        source: 'development'
        target: 'master'
```